# Using OpenGL in OpenCL kernel

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl, opencl

Is there any way to use OpenGL methods when using OpenCL kernels? I would like to vectorize my voxel-based alogorithm using GPGPU. To give a simple exmaple a paste the current code of my algorithm and maybe somebody could help me with this issue.

```
for(int x = 0; x < voxelWorld->getVoxelsX(); x++)
    for(int y = 0; y < voxelWorld->getVoxelsY(); y++)
        for(int z = 0; z < voxelWorld->getVoxelsZ(); z++)
        {
            glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef((x - voxelWorld->offsetX())*voxelWorld->getVoxelSize(),
                         (y - voxelWorld->offsetY())*voxelWorld->getVoxelSize(),
                         (z - voxelWorld->offsetZ())*voxelWorld->getVoxelSize());
            if(this->doRenderWireframeWorld)
            {
                glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
                glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                this->renderVoxel(false);
                glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
            }

            if(voxelWorld->getVoxel(x, y, z) && this->doRenderVoxels)
            {
                glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
                this->renderVoxel(true);
            }
            glPopMatrix();
        }
```

I know that there should be only one loop instead of three nested loops. So I would change the code a little bit to:

`for(int i = 0; i < voxelWorld->getVoxelsX() * voxelWorld->getVoxelsY() * voxelWorld->getVoxelsZ(); i++)`

It would be a good start to pass the data to the OpenCL kernel, but what now? I would like to do the rendeing inside OpenCL kernel (all the `glPushMatrix`, `glEnable`) but I assume it is impossible. Does anybody have any expericence doing such things?

Comment: Parallelize it by using modern OpenGL, in particular shaders with per-vertex data and transformation in place of a global matrix stack.

Comment: So there is no place for OpenCL when optimizing rendering?

Comment: You can mix the two, where buffers are shared between OpenGL and OpenCL, but for the example above, I would also stick to OpenGL vertex shaders as suggested by delnan.

Comment: @PawełJastrzębski Well, you can write your own software renderer in OpenCL, but unless your renderer drastically deviates from rasterization, it's of no use. OpenGL gives access to the *same hardware resources*, in a more convenient way.

Comment: @PawełJastrzębski If there are only voxels, a raytrace algorithm can be fast enough with some acceleration structures computed on opencl.

Comment: I am thinkig about writing my own raytrace algorithm. I'm not yet concerned if I can do it with my marching cubes alogirtm. But it would be a good idea to implement it along with raytracer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rendering with OpenGL is already parallelized by the GPU, you don't have to do anything further to it than just make the OpenGL drawing calls. The OpenGL implementation queues them into batches sent to the GPU, the GPU will process vertices and fragments in parallel (because that's what GPUs do).

Of course to really unleash the power of the GPU you must stop starving it by using the deprecated, old fashioned, outdated, discarded immediate mode. I.e. don't use glBegin, glVertex, glEnd. Use Vertex Arrays contained in Vertex Buffer Objects.

(Full disclosure: If you'd use Display Lists you could make use of GPUs parallelization power even using immediate mode. But this is not recommended for new programs.)

Comment: So the VBO-way is the parallelized way of rendering? What's with instancing?

Comment: Parallelized on TMU/ROP only? No compute cores?

Comment: @PawełJastrzębski: No, VBOs have nothing to do with parallelization. The GPU will **always** parallelize the rendering process. The purpose of VBOs is to place the data from which the GPU renders the picture in memory which the GPU can access fast. Immediate mode gives the GPU rendering commands in very small chunks. The GPU will be done rendering the pixels (in parallel) to the framebuffer, long before your program is able to send the next `glVertex` command. In short: Immediate mode is starving the GPU.

Comment: CPU mUltithreaded rendering will come with mantle. But not for opengl right?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: Modern GPUs (everything built after 2008) make no distinction between those. The same shader cores are used for vertex setup, geometry shaders, fragment shaders and general computation. When you render, say, a triangle that covers some area on the framebuffers, the fragment operations will be executed in parallel.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: I don't know, I've not seen the Mantle specification. I asked AMD for it, but right now it's given only to selected developers. But why care? It's not like you have to explicitly use multiple threads on GPUs. In fact concurrent access on GPUs is usually degrading performance. When you render some primitive that covers area in the framebuffer, all the pixels it will touch are processed in parallel. Similar all the vertices that make up a primitive get processed in parallel, and if you're using tesselation shaders, their result as well. That's all happening automatically

Comment: @datenwolf thank you. Which one could be faster? Using a vbo and changing data of vbo using opencl-gpu (interoperability) or using pure shading language to update and render?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: Since the OpenGL shader language (GLSL) can't do anything on its own (technically it's more like a filter through which the data issued by OpenGL rendering commands is passed through) it would be the the combination of OpenCL + OpenGL interop. However since OpenGL-4 there are compute shaders, which give sort of OpenCL capabilities to OpenGL. However OpenCL is still more flexible, and also supported for some OpenGL-3 GPUs.